# Column missing in the Controller query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET and I want to display an image stored in my database (SQL Server) as a `varbinary(max)` and I am using `SQLbinary` in my model to represent it.

I have a model representing the table :

```cs
namespace models
{
    [Table("Web.TestView")]
    public class WebTestView
    {
        [Key]
        public int TestId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(513)]
        public string Namespace { get; set; }
        public SqlBinary ImageData { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

one DbContext containing a reference to that db Table:

```cs
public virtual DbSet<WebTestView> WebTestView { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<WebTestView>()
                .Property(e => e.Namespace)
                .IsUnicode(false);
}
```

And a controller calling that table:

```cs
var query = _db.WebTestView;
testViews = query.ToList();
```

The issue is that ImageData is **always** null in every testViews.

```
{SELECT     [Extent1].[TestId] AS [TestId],
     [Extent1].[Namespace] AS [Namespace],
     [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
     [Extent1].[EndTime] AS [EndTime]
    FROM [Web].[TestView] AS [Extent1]}
```

Yes, ImageData is **absent**.

Does anyone has an idea why this IQueryable request is not asking for any ImageData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Right, I figured out that the issue was coming from the `SQLBinary` Type, simply had to change it to byte[].

That is surprising because I create this data as a `SQLBinary`, so basically:

`SQLBinary` (c#) -> `VARBINARY(MAX)` (SQL Server) -> `byte[]` (c#)

> Now my question is about why can we convert it one way but not the other?